# Nicholas Gisin's papers about Time in Physics

Tags: time, specific-reference

I recently read the article from  [QuantaMagazine](https://www.quantamagazine.org/does-time-really-flow-new-clues-come-from-a-century-old-approach-to-math-20200407/) which says

> Over the past year, the Swiss physicist Nicolas Gisin has published **four papers** that attempt to dispel the fog surrounding time in physics. As Gisin sees it, the problem all along has been mathematical

I tried searching for these four papers but not able to find them. If anyone could provide DOI for all these papers, it would be of great help for me.

Comment: Look up in the google scholar page of Nicolas Gisin. https://scholar.google.ch/citations?hl=fr&user=SwLIrjAAAAAJ&view_op=list_works&sortby=pubdate#d=gs_md_cita-d&u=%2Fcitations%3Fview_op%3Dview_citation%26hl%3Dfr%26user%3DSwLIrjAAAAAJ%26sortby%3Dpubdate%26citation_for_view%3DSwLIrjAAAAAJ%3A1Aeql8wG3wEC%26tzom%3D-330

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the papers listed with their preprint links:

- Indeterminism in Physics, Classical Chaos and Bohmian Mechanics: Are Real Numbers Really Real? - [linked here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10670-019-00165-8.pdf)
- Real numbers are the hidden variables of classical mechanics - [linked here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s40509-019-00211-8.pdf)
- Physics without Determinism: Alternative Interpretations of Classical Physics - [linked here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.03697.pdf)
- Classical and intuitionistic mathematical languages shape our understanding of time
  in physics - [linked here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.01653.pdf)